# How to load Google map in background in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have fragment for map in XML file as below,

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" >
    </fragment>
```

In which activity I am displaying the Google map, that is not a main activity. I am redirecting to map activity from my main activity on button click. There is no any problem with map. But when I click on button of main activity then the process stops for sometime and suddenly black screen arrives in front and after sometime, map activity displays the map. It is not expected behaviour of application. Is there any way to load that map after map activity loaded? I mean loading map in background?

Answer (score 2):

Use getMapAsync() (introduced in Google Play Services v6.5.87) instead of getMap() then Implement OnMapReadyCallback on your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    // do something with map
}
```