# How to load polylines and points on google map v2 for android in the background?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I'm working on a map app for cycling. The challenge I'm facing is loading routes which are very long. Routes which are anything longer than 10000km (6200 miles) is taking an astronomical amount of time to load to the map.

```
...

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    TimingLogger timings = new TimingLogger("maplocs_timer_log", "loadSavedRoute");

    for (int i = 0; i < mLocationDirections.size(); i++) {
        Direction direction = mLocationDirections.get(i);
        direction.setEndLocationMarker(mMap.addMarker(direction.getMarkerOptions()));
        if (i > 0)
            direction.setPolyline(mMap.addPolyline(direction.getPolylineOptions()));
    }
}
```

Here, I'm retrieving the route data in the background from the db (offline store), creating the markerOptions and even the PolylineOptions to add to the map. However the actual adding to the map is taking a long time. 
This peice of code in postExecute of the AsyncTask takes 9000+ ms to execute on a Moto G4 and about 2000+ ms on a OnePlus 5T.

So, how can I move this loading to the map in the background so that it does not block the UI thread and crash the app?

Comment: maybe this would help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609034/how-to-load-google-map-in-background-in-android

Comment: Thanks for the comment and link. The problem however, is not about loading the map - that is happening fine. The problem is with loading the data on the map - the points and polylines.

Comment: You have to be clever here and sample your data. There's no point adding all the markers and routes for 10K kms. When the map is zoomed out, sample/aggregate your data and add few direct routes and markers. As the user zooms in, update your markers and routes.

This question is not about performance. It's about Math. Adding thousands of data points will always cause lag.

Comment: @Froyo Thanks for that idea. You are right. In my map app there's an option to open the created route in google maps and the same route which I created which was lagging so much took no lag to load on the Maps app and I was wondering how thats happening. However after you commented I noticed more closely and saw that the maps apps is also not loading all the points. Even they are sampling the data as you said. I shall do the same. Thanks.